# Outputs of polynomials form a regular n-gon in 2 dimensional real space

Tags: polynomials

Let $n\geq 3$ be an integer. Let $f(x), g(x)$ be polynomials with real coefficiants such that the points $(f(1),g(1)), (f(2),g(2)),\cdots (f(n),g(n))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ form a regular $n$-gon in counterclockwise order. Prove that $\max(\deg f, \deg g)\geq n-1$.

I know that there is a solution which puts the polygon on the complex plane and setting $p(x)=f(x)+ig(x)$, then choosing suitable $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ to scale $p(x)$ to have roots at $n$th roots of unity.

I was wondering if there is a solution without complex numbers.

Here is some progress: We know that $(f(k+1)-f(k))^2+(g(k+1)-g(k))^2=c$, for $1\leq k\leq n$ (with $n+1=1$). Then I set $p(x)=(f(x+1)-f(x))^2+(g(x+1)-g(x))^2-c$, which conviniently factors as $p(x)=q(x)(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)$. This gave me the bound $\max(\deg f, \deg g)\geq \frac{n+2}{2}$. I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: Look at [Chebyshev Polynomial of the Second Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html).  The demo [n-Gon Polynomials](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NGonPolynomials/)  shows how these can be used to construct n-gons.